# When using an SSH alias, why is SSH ignoring my (valid) Kerberos ticket?

Tags: ssh, alias, kerberos

I am successfully connecting to my university's network via ssh with Kerberos ticket authentication. Normal, verbose operation (kinit a ticket, then ssh user@hostname) works fine.

**The Problem**

When setting up ssh aliases in the `~/.ssh/config` file, however, ssh completely ignores Kerberos and prompts for my password. (See debugging output below.)

Why is this? How might I configure it to use Kerberos?

*Note: normal ssh operation with Kerberos continues to work before and after attempts with ssh aliases. Additionally ssh aliases work as intended when provided with a login pw.*

*(System: Mac OS 10.11.4, Darwin Kernel Version 15.4.0, OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8, Kerberos 5 release 1.7)*

**Debugging Output**

When running SSH from the CL I added `-vvv` for verbose debug info, then diffed the output. I've included the portions that differed significantly.

```
$ ssh -vvv [ssh-alias]

debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
atmills@login.engin.umich.edu's password:
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to login.engin.umich.edu ([141.213.74.56]:22).
```

```
$ ssh -vvv [user@host]

debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex
debug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug3: Trying to reverse map address 141.213.74.58.
debug2: we sent a gssapi-with-mic packet, wait for reply
debug1: Delegating credentials
debug1: Delegating credentials
debug1: Authentication succeeded (gssapi-with-mic).
Authenticated to login.engin.umich.edu ([141.213.74.58]:22).
```

Comment: compare verbose logs (`-vvv`) from both connections. There should be no difference in using and not-using alias.

Comment: A `HostName` entry with the fully qualified hostname might be a good thing to have.

Comment: @Jakuje Thanks for the help. There were significant differences, which I included in a post update. Thoughts?

Comment: @thrig Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Do you have anything besides this alias in your .config file?  Is this just a one-liner or is it complex?

Comment: Is this the only difference? How does your `.ssh/config` look like?

Answer (score 1):

Kerberos as I've seen it configured deals with fully qualified hostnames (`gato.example.org`) and not unqualified hosts (`gato`); using an unqualified hostname produces for me in testing `ssh` debug lines of:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1:  Miscellaneous failure (see text)
Error from KDC: LOOKING_UP_SERVER while looking up 'host/gato@EXAMPLE.ORG' (cached result, timeout in 1089 sec)
```

This is due to the kerberos hosts typically only having fully qualified host principal entries in their `/etc/krb5.keytab` file:

```
[root@gato ~]# strings /etc/krb5.keytab | head -3
EXAMPLE.ORG
host
gato.example.org
```

Your logs appear to both use the fully qualified `login.engin.umich.edu` hostname so your problem may be something else, though in general when dealing with kerberos it would be best to force fully qualified hostnames in `~/.ssh/config`, either manually:

```
Host gato.example.org gato bubba
    Hostname gato.example.org
```

Or instead via the `CanonicalizeHostname` keyword (see `ssh_config(5)` for details and caveats).

Another point to note is that `login.engin.umich.edu` is a pool of hosts; one thing to test would be specific nodes in this pool are misconfigured for kerberos and thus dumping you back to password auth, though that would take editing `/etc/hosts` to contain something like:

```
141.213.74.56 login.engin.umich.edu
```

And remembering to remove the test entries when done. (Using the IP address is no good for kerberos, you need to use the hostname, hence the need to munge `/etc/hosts` for testing.)